# FBLogin assign delegate from UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegation

I have a FBLogin (Facebook SDK) button I am using in a view being replicated throughout many of my view controllers. It seems I cannot set a UIView as a delegate to the Facebook SDK, so I am trying to create a seperate ViewController to handle the delegate functions of the Facebook  SDK.

**Header file:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>

@class AppDelegate, FBDelegateViewController;
@interface UserView : UIView {

    AppDelegate *appDelegate;

    IBOutlet UIView *contentView;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *userImage;
    IBOutlet UILabel *firstName;
    FBDelegateViewController *fbDelegate;
    IBOutlet FBLoginView *FacebookLogin;

}

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIView *contentView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *firstName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) AppDelegate *appDelegate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) FBDelegateViewController *fbDelegate;
```

**Currently in my implementation I am doing the following:**

```
#import "UserView.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "FBDelegateViewController.h"
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>

@implementation UserView

@synthesize contentView, firstName, appDelegate, fbDelegate;

- (void)awakeFromNib {

    fbDelegate = [[FBDelegateViewController alloc] init];
    appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"UserView" owner:self options:nil];
    [self addSubview:self.contentView];
    [userImage.layer setCornerRadius:21.5];

    [FacebookLogin setDelegate:fbDelegate];

}

@end
```

**The application crashes with the following:**

**** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView setDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa5e4f80'*

In interface builder the UIView that contains the FBLogin item is set.

I also tried delegation with the UIView as well, but it looks like a UIView cannot be a delegate for a FBLogin?

Sorry, new territory here. Typically have used the associated view controller as a delegate - but want to understand external delegation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It seems I cannot set a UIView as a delegate to the Facebook SDK, so I
>   am trying to create a seperate ViewController to handle the delegate
>   functions of the Facebook SDK.

This assumption is false, any NSObject can be set as the delegate **as long as** it implements the `FBLoginViewDelegate` protocol

This can be done like this:

```
@interface UserView : UIView <FBLoginViewDelegate> {
```

After you do this, you can set this view as the delegate!

Comment: I am getting the following error when I click the facebook login box: -[UIView setReadPermissions:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa845990

- this is when I try to run the UIView as a delegate.

Comment: What is your "FacebookLogin" object? Can you post more code about your issue? What object's delegate are you trying to set and what object are you setting it to